# Wrap JSON field names in quotes using vim search and replace

Tags: regex, vim

I have a simple json file that isn't well formatted it looks like:

```
{ ID: '092558667',  
  NAME: 'Store Made',  
  PARENT_CATEGORY_ID: '692558669',  
  INCLUDED_IN_NET_SALES: '1' }
```

All I need to do is wrap the field names in double quotes. In vim the closest I have gotten is to wrap the field name and the colon in quotes - obviously I need to figure out how to get the string without the colon wrapped. Here's what I am trying:

```
:%s/[A-Z_]*:/"&"
```

If I leave the colon out of the query the whole file ends up being selected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [capture groups](http://www.vimregex.com/#backreferences):

```
%s/\([A-Z_]*\):/"\1":/
```

To handle already quoted keys properly:

```
%s/"\?\([A-Z_]*\)"\?:/"\1":/
```

Comment: vim golf: `%s/[A-Z_]\+\ze:/"&"`

Answer (score 3):

Ok, with the information above I ended up with this:

```
:%s/[ \t]\([A-Za-z_].*\):/"\1":/
```

- it supports upper- *and* lowercase chars
- it skips already quoted fields

Since this can be considered a completion, I mapped it to a vim completion shortcut ctrl-x ctrl-j in .vimrc (they all start with ctrl-x ) :

```
:noremap <C-x><C-j> :%s/[ \t]\([A-Za-z_].*\):/"\1":/<CR>
```